# Printing DVD and CD inserts is / are quick and simple

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, grammatical-number

> Printing DVD/CD Inserts Is Quick And Simple  With Our User-Friendly Online Ordering System.

or

> Printing DVD/CD Inserts are Quick And Simple  With Our User-Friendly Online Ordering System.

I assume that if the quality is about the process, "Printing" is singular, so "is," now "are" it should be If I'm trying to say a quality about the inserts but not about the process.

Please help!

Comment: It would be _DVD/CD Inserts are Quick And Simple With Our User-Friendly Online Ordering System._ Is that what you are wondering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Printing** in this case is a gerund. It functions as a noun. As you have guessed, in your first example, it functions as a singular entity, so it takes a singular verb.

Here's the important part. A gerund is a noun. It works like every other noun. It has a singular form and a plural form. The plural of a gerund is always formed regularly, so it takes an **s**. If you wanted to think of multiple **printings**, you would first have to make the gerund plural. Then you could choose a plural verb to match it.

It's hard to imagine a plural usage in the sentence you are working with. But **printings** is possible in some circumstances. Consider:

> We printed DVD inserts every day this week. The Monday printing went perfectly. The Tuesday printing was a failure. The Wednesday printing was a partial success. *These printings are never the same.*

The singular **printing** can never take a plural verb.

Comment: Thank You Mr. Jeffrey Carney, great answer! Love it